# как удалять сразу несколько объектов одной кнопкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Суть программы:
пишите имена в entry и он выводит имена вниз,так вот,когда нажимаешь на кнопку **clear all names** все имена должны стереться я сделал это с помощью `.destroy()`, но когда нажимаешь на кнопку **clear all names** стирается только одно имя.Как сделать чтобы стирались все имена?
**Вот сама программа:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
# --- clear_and_save ---
def clear_and_save():
    # --- names commands ---
    global save_lbl
    save_lbl = Label(text=message.get())
    save_lbl.pack()
    # --- entry clear command ---
    name.delete(0,'end')
# --- clear function ---
def clear():
    destroy_object = [save_lbl]
    for i in destroy_object:
        i.destroy()

welcome = Label(text='write down')
# --- people's name ---
message = StringVar()
name = Entry(textvariable=message)
#--- save btn ---
save_btn = Button(root,text='save >>',command=clear_and_save)
# --- clear btn ---
clear_btn = Button(root,text='clear all names',command=clear)
# --- pack all objects ---
welcome.pack()
name.pack()
save_btn.pack()
clear_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая простая реализация вашей проблемы это просто обновлять один виджет, а не создавать каждый раз новый

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')


# --- clear_and_save ---
def clear_and_save():
    # --- names commands ---
    save_lbl["text"] = save_lbl["text"] + "\n" + message.get()
    # --- entry clear command ---
    name.delete(0, 'end')


# --- clear function ---
def clear():
    save_lbl.destroy()


save_lbl = Label()
welcome = Label(text='write down')
# --- people's name ---
message = StringVar()
name = Entry(textvariable=message)
# --- save btn ---
save_btn = Button(root, text='save >>', command=clear_and_save)
# --- clear btn ---
clear_btn = Button(root, text='clear all names', command=clear)
# --- pack all objects ---
welcome.pack()
name.pack()
save_btn.pack()
clear_btn.pack()

save_lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Ну или если вам принципиально создавать все время `Label`  то можно все это засунуть во `Frame` и за счет функции `pack_slaves()` удалить их `forget()`ом

```
from tkinter import *


# --- clear_and_save ---
def clear_and_save():
    # --- names commands ---

    Label(frame, text=message.get()).pack()

    # --- entry clear command ---
    name.delete(0, 'end')


# --- clear function ---
def clear():
    frame_list = frame.pack_slaves()
    for i in frame_list:
        i.forget()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
frame = Frame(root)

welcome = Label(text='write down')
# --- people's name ---
message = StringVar()
name = Entry(textvariable=message)
# --- save btn ---
save_btn = Button(root, text='save >>', command=clear_and_save)
# --- clear btn ---
clear_btn = Button(root, text='clear all names', command=clear)
# --- pack all objects ---
welcome.pack()
name.pack()
save_btn.pack()
clear_btn.pack()
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```